# What is hexa MIDI message for G2, D♯3, D3 in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, midi, coremidi

I want to send MIDI notes using HEXA package.

G2, D♯3, D3

using coreMIDI in swift

Comment: What is the problem? Don't you know Swift? CoreMIDI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please See below Midi Packet For above mention Note.

For G2

```
    var packet1:MIDIPacket = MIDIPacket()
    packet1.timeStamp = 0
    packet1.length = 3
    packet1.data.0 = 0x90 // Note On event channel 1
    packet1.data.1 = 0x37 // Note C3
    packet1.data.2 = 0x7F // Velocity
```

For D#3
 just Update

```
packet1.data.1 = 0x3F
```

For D3
 just Update

```
packet1.data.1 = 0x3E
```

For More Codes, Open this file [MidiOutpout](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qmw11W7AZOJTcOvbvFCCCTfdwRYfvhIq/view?usp=sharing) In Midi Monitor Application